# How to make search, enter text and replace a line in bash?

Tags: bash

I've been trying to write a bash code (experimenting) where bash will ask (Enter Text) and the user will enter a certain text lets say (I am new) and the text (I am new) will be moved to a line called User=I am new.

So, here is a cfg file named **xyz.cfg**

```
User 
Name 
Address 
Country
```

and here is the bash script called **test** and with only **echo $Input > $file** the bash replace the whole file with the **entered text** but I want to keep the config as it is and add the **Enter Text:** value to the line **User** but this doesn't help, the code below,

```
#! /bin/sh
file=/root/xyz.cfg
echo "Enter text:"
read Input
echo $Input > $file **(confused here)** **(it replaces the whole cfg)**
```

Another line I thought of is here, but it doesn't work. I am not good with these so I hope it's solved; I tried searching the web with zero luck.

(doesn't work)

```
#! /bin/sh
file=/root/xyz.cfg
echo "Enter text:"
read Input
echo $Input > sed '/User/a' xyz.cfg
```

(doesn't work)

```
#! /bin/sh
file=/root/xyz.cfg
echo "Enter text:"
read Input
echo $Input > sed '/User/a' $file
```

Edit:

When a someone is asked for **Enter Text:** while running the bash script **./test** and the someone typed **Entered Text from bash promot** the entered $Input (**Entered Text from bash promot**) should move to **xyz.cfg** and add the line to the Variable **User:**

Finally, the **xyz.cfg** should look like

```
    User: Entered Text from bash prompt
    Name 
    Address 
    Country
```

Before it looked like this,

```
    User: 
    Name
    Address 
    Country
```

Edit2: [This GIF](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HsxViYY.gif) might explain what I need.

Comment: Are you wanting to be prompted for each replacement in the file, or just once for the entire file?

Comment: Once or maybe two three times, but for now lets just say once,

But it should ask, **Enter Line:** and when user types in Enter Line: **name**

Script should add **name** to line **User** in **xyz.cfg**

Comment: Could you please clarify what you actually need regarding the number of prompts? The difference between "once per file" and "once per **User** in the file" is significant.

Comment: Also, what should the file look like in the end?

Comment: @Erayd #! /bin/sh
file=/root/xyz.cfg
echo "Enter text:"
read Input
echo $Input > $file **(confused here) (it replaces the whole cfg)**

Comment: @BenjaminW. finally the xyz.cfg should look like User: new text here and rest remain the same. I've edited the thread with how the final file should look.

Comment: @Nov2 Your most recent comment really hasn't helped me understand your requirements. Can you please just answer, do you need to be prompted once for each time **User** appears in the file, or be prompted once only for the entire file, and then use that same entered text for every occurance of **User** within the file?

Regarding your confusion - you overwrote the file because you used `>`.

Comment: @Erayd

I've updated the thread,

When a someone is asked for **Enter Text:** while running the bash script **./test** and the someone typed **Entered Text from bash promot** the entered $Input (**Entered Text from bash promot**) should move to **xyz.cfg** and add the line to the Variable **User:** 

Finally the **xyz.cfg** should look like

        User: Entered Text from bash promot
        Name 
        Address 
        Country

Before it looked like this,

        User: 
        Name
        Address 
        Country

Comment: @Erayd  I got what you meant by overwrote

I used echo $Input > $file so it over wrote the $Input to the $file so how to achieve what I want to achieve, if you understood what I meant, I would be helpful!

Please look at the gif, I hope you will get what I need.

https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HsxViYY.gif

Comment: You shouldn't mark a question as "solved", see this help article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Instead, you should mark an answer that worked for you as accepted.

Comment: @Erayd I have one final question, suppose, I got, a cfg like this,

dov "textone - 10 may"
dov "i'm good today - 11 may"
dov "" 
dov ""
dov ""

because dov and " " are same how will the bash write using your following code.

Comment: @Erayd sorry for that but even with shift + enter it is being posted like this.

As the question continues,

Is there any way to sed search same variable because my config has for example five User: and I want the script to write on **4th User: line**

Comment: @Nov2 Are you wanting it to prompt you each time it sees a **User:** line, so that if the file contains five such lines, you are asked to enter custom text five times?

Comment: @Erayd Yes, one would be that -- **wanting it to prompt you each time it sees a User: line, so that if the file contains five such lines, you are asked to enter custom text five times.**

Second would be --- I also want to know how to make bash write for example lets take **User:**, if the file contains **five such lines**, I am asked **once** and the bash will **write** on line **three** and **skip** line **one** **two** **four** and **five.**

Comment: @Nov2 I have edited my answer to show a multiple-prompt approach. The second question in your most recent comment is a completely different problem, and should be asked in an independent question, rather than trying to add it on to this one. Using a counter variable inside the loop will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll add the second question on a different set. For now I'll be experimenting it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/tmp/test.cfg

echo -n "Enter text: "
read INPUT
sed -i "s/User:/& $INPUT/" "$FILE"
```

This uses sed to do an in-place search / replace (`-i`) which appends the entered text after the first occurence of `User:` on each line within `$FILE`.

`&` refers to the matched portion of the text - it's essentially saying "replace `<thing>` with `<thing> <entered text>`."

---

If you need to prompt for text each time a matching `User:` line is encountered, you can use the following approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/tmp/test.cfg
ORIGINAL=$(cat "$FILE")

truncate -s 0 "$FILE"
while read LINE; do
    if `grep -q 'User:' <<< "$LINE"`; then
        echo -n "Enter text: "
        read INPUT < /dev/tty
        sed "s/User:/& $INPUT/" <<< "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
    else
        echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
    fi
done <<< "$ORIGINAL"
```

This second approach does the following:

1. Reads the entire file contents into a variable;
2. Removes the existing file contents;
3. Loops over each line of the original content, and:

   1. If the line contains `User:`, prompt for and append the custom text;
   2. Append the line to the file.

Comment: in reference to your first answer, 

#!/bin/bash
FILE=/tmp/test.cfg

echo -n "Enter text: "
read INPUT
sed -i "s/User:/& $INPUT/" "$FILE"**

I want the bash script to **create a new line** at the end of the file (test.cfg) named as **input value** and the **text entered**, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Say, I want the input in the test.cfg be like **INPUT VALUE NEWLINEENTERED** where the user will only type **newlineentered** but the **INPUT VALUE** text **should be automatically wrote at the end of the test.cfg file** and after the Input Value line the entered text should be present.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `echo` with no argument will output a newline.

Comment: Regarding your second question, could you please rephrase it? I don't understand what you are wanting to achieve. An example might help.

Comment: I fixed it by using echo. Thanks. Btw, do you know how to change terminal default color?

Comment: Depends on your terminal, and is nothing to do with this question - if you cannot figure it out, post a new one :-).

Comment: I figured out by add the -fg color to /.bashrc